# Migrating MariaDB cannot find files anymore

Tags: migration, mariadb, database-administration, database-backup

I had to reset my dedicated server, so i backuped the whole /var/lib/mysql directory (stored in OVH Backup Storage).

Today on my clean dedicated, i reinstalled mariadb and so putted the whole /var/lib/mysql directory of the backup into /var/lib/mysql (the new).
I just copied the databases directories (i also have other files like ibdata etc.).

But the MariaDB files don't load, so i tried running the following:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --all-databases
```

And i get tons of Table "..." doesn't exists, while i copied the database directory.

So i gave a run copying the ibdata file, and mariadb wasn't starting anymore.

Do anyone have a solution for copying my MariaDB databases?

I also chowned the directory

**EDIT:**

I see pretty much everywhere peoples talking about a .ibd file needed, while backuping that file wasn't displayed and not saved.
As i said i use MariaDB and i also have an ibdata file.

Comment: Did you preserve owners and permissions while copying the files?

Comment: I also did chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Edited adding more informations

Comment: Do you have the same configuration on old and new MySQL installation?

Comment: Yes, same password, user and etc.

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Well, i can see something like "170319 17:21:59 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table panel/users from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
how you can resolve the problem."